# get number of rows from last query, Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress platform, while generating a mysql query I want to display the number of rows from that query. An example is shown below.

```
$query = ("SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_term_relationships.object_id
     FROM wp_posts
     LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
     WHERE post_date <= '$now'
     AND term_taxonomy_id = '$catid'
     AND post_date >= '$then' 
     AND post_status = 'publish'");
```

Now when I generate this query into phpmyadmin, it gives the following output 
*Showing rows 0 - 5 (6 total, Query took 0.0013 sec)*

I want to display the number of rows i-e 6 total ...
so what function i must use to display it ??

Comment: How do you run the query? Do you use `wpdb`?

Comment: yes i use $wpdb->posts.ID etc.. Problem solved see the answer by ulvund

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = ("SELECT count(*), wp_posts.ID, wp_term_relationships.object_id
 FROM wp_posts
 LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
 WHERE post_date <= '$now'
 AND term_taxonomy_id = '$catid'
 AND post_date >= '$then' 
 AND post_status = 'publish'");
```

Comment: Thanks man, Thanks alot... i was working on this piece of code count(*) from last night ...